# Parse input fields to formated json with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am busy with a form duplication, when submit is pressed, I would like it to parse to json in the following format:

```
{ "dependant1": [
  { "name": "daniel"},
  ],"dependant2": [
  { "name": "steve"},
  ]
}
```

with each added dependant, at the moment, if i add more then one dependant it returns "{} {}" but if theres only one dependant it returns "{"name":"steve"}.

any help greatly apreciated.
Heres the code:

jQuery:

```
        //Clone Tracking
var g_counter = 1;
var d_counter = 1;
var dependant = ["dependant"];
var group;
//Clone Tracking
//General Variables
var name_input_groups = ["name-group-1"];
//General Variables
//Generate variables
var name_fields=[0];
var name_input = "<input class='name' />";
//Generate variables
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    jQuery(name_fields).each(function() {
        jQuery(name_input).appendTo('#name-group-1');
    });
    //populate jquery generated fields
    //Cloning Function
    jQuery('#clone').click(function() {
        clone_dependant();
    });

    function clone_dependant() {
        // Store the value of the previous Id to insert the cloned div..
        var oldId = g_counter;
        g_counter++;
        // Clone the Dependant Div and set a new id
        var $clonedDiv = jQuery('#dependant-1').clone(false).attr('id', 'dependant-'+g_counter);
        var name_newDiv = 'name-group-'+ g_counter;
        // Find div's inside the cloned object and set a new id's
        $clonedDiv.find('#name-group-1').attr('id',"name-group-" + g_counter );
        // You don't need to Loop thru the inputs to set the value
        $clonedDiv.find('input').val('');
        // Insert the cloned object 
        $clonedDiv.insertAfter("#dependant-" + oldId);
        name_input_groups.push(name_newDiv);
    };
    //Cloning Function
    function validate_gen() {};
//submit function
var dep_counter = 0
jQuery('#submit').click(function(){
    $('.dependant').each(function(k, v){
        dep_counter++;
        var dependants = {};
    dependants['name'] = jQuery("#name-group-" + dep_counter).find('input').val();
        var json = JSON.stringify(dependants); 
        console.log(json);
    });
});
});
```

and heres the HTML:

```
<div id="dependant-1" class="dependant">
    name<div id="name-group-1"></div>
</div>
<div id="test"></div>

<button id="clone">clone</button>
<button id="submit">submit</button>
```

and the jsFiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/TzRu8/2/

Thanks.

Comment: You posted a whole lot of irrelevant code, which is the part you're having trouble with? Where is the part that constructs the object? BTW, it doesn't become JSON until you convert it to a string for transmission; until then, it's just a Javascript object.

Comment: sorry, ill quickly edit it and try correct it...

Comment: corrected it.. sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply used the following code and it worked perefectly:

```
    var result = {};
var dependants;
jQuery('#submit').click(function(){
    $('.dependant').each(function(k, v){
        dependants = {};
        dependants['name'] = $(v).find('.name').val();
        dependants['surname'] = $(v).find('.surname').val();
        dependants['id'] = idNumber;
        dependants['age'] = $(v).find('.age').val();
        dependants['gender'] = $(v).find('.gender').val();
        dependants['cell'] = cell_values;
        dependants['passport'] = pass_values;
        dependants['relationship'] = $(v).find('.relationship:checked').val();
        result['dependant'+g_counter] = [dependants];
    });

    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(result);

    console.log(jsonData);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {parameters: jsonData}
    });

});
```

Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

Your json is malformed. You could use http://jsonlint.com/ to 
validate your  json format.

For instance, this is a correct format

```
 { "dependant1": [{ "name": "daniel"}] },
 { "dependant2": [{ "name": "steve" }] }
```

You would need to re-write your script to produce a valid json format. Follow the pattern above to add more dependants .... unless steve is a sub-dependant of daniel, then the structure is closer to what you started with.

Comment: thank you, but that does still not give me a solution... im still trying on my side.. hopefully ill get a solution.. thanks anyways :)..

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code.

1:

```
$clonedDiv.find('#name-group-1').attr('id',"#name-group-" + g_counter );
```

should be with no '#' before 'name-group':

```
$clonedDiv.find('#name-group-1').attr('id',"name-group-" + g_counter );
```

2:

```
dependants['name'] = jQuery("#name-group-" + g_counter ).val();
```

where 'g_counter' should be 'dep_counter'.

**[update]**

Oh, I'm sorry I forget the third error:

```
dependants['name'] = jQuery("#name-group-" + dep_counter ).val();
```

should be:

```
dependants['name'] = jQuery("#name-group-" + dep_counter ).find('input').val();
```

After you fix these errors, you can get what you want using the following code:

```
var dep_counter = 0
var result = {};
jQuery('#submit').click(function(){
    $('.dependant').each(function(k, v){
        dep_counter++;
        var dependants = {};
        dependants['name'] = jQuery("#name-group-" + dep_counter).find('input').val();
        result['dependant'+dep_counter] = [dependants];
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

Comment: Does this solute the problem? Or you can correct it, then continue your question.